# Didn't get the Famous Question badge

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges, views, view-badges

I am active on Stack Overflow. I saw that one of my question has more than 10,000 views but the [Famous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/28/famous-question) badge wasn't awarded to me.

Why not?

Comment: Would you improve that question without invalidating any of the current answers? It shows no original research effort.  I'd hate to think that 10K views saw a question like that and think of Stack Overflow as a code-writing service as a result.

Comment: I have improved it . I was just started learning android and was new to this site so may be thats why i have asked it simply. Wasnt know to use this site at that time thank you to leeting me know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

None of your questions actually have 10,000 views.

[This question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089300/how-can-i-change-the-image-of-imageviewandroid) has about 9,700 views, and gets **rounded** to 10k in the smaller box when viewing the questions list. You still have a little bit to go.

Comment: okkk thanks to clarify the things. I was just wondering ... :)

Comment: yeah i have just seen that just put my cursor on the views its showing how many times this question has been viewed. But any way thanks.